# Generate Random Numbers Until a certain

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write some code (using a while loop) that will generate random numbers (between 1 and 10) until the number 7 is generated.

Here is what I've got so far, but it's just stuck in a loop of printing random numbers between 1 and 10.

```
num = ""
while num != 7
    print rand(1..10).to_s
end
puts "over"
```

I understand why it's looping without end, but I'm unsure of how else to generate the random numbers and still end the loop when a 7 appears.

Comment: _"I understand why it's looping without end"_ – what do you think why it doesn't end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem for this code is that you generate an infinite loop because num is always "", you need to update the variable num inside the while loop like this:

```
num = ""
while num != 7
  num = rand(1..10)
  puts num
end
puts "over"
```

in this case, you do not know when the loop will stop, but in each loop it can stop with probability 1/10, this is not a good practice, you nedd to know when the loop stops, so will be better to add a variable for maximum number of tries like this. And also you do not need to transform dthe number to string to print it:

```
num = 0
max_tries = 100
try = 1
guess = 7

while (try < max_tries && num != guess)
  num = rand(1..10)
  try = try + 1
  puts num
end

if (try >= max_tries)
  puts "you do not get the guess"
else
  puts "over"
end
```

and you get this:

```
[4] pry(main)> 9
9
3
4
9
6
9
8
4
5
9
10
4
3
7
over
=> true
```

Comment: Thanks for the added lesson in there. Lot's of good answers on this, but I like that you added in that extra bit. You get the answer.

Comment: Shouldn't you increment `try` somewhere?

Comment: Sorry I forget to update, try in each loop pass, thanks @Stefan

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do it, for example:

```
loop do
  num = rand(1..10)
  print num
  break if num == 7
end
```

Also, to make your code work:

```
num = ""
while num != '7'
    num = rand(1..10).to_s
    print num
end
puts "over"
```

reason in that you convert `num` to string and compare it with `integer`

Answer (score 2):

```
puts (number = rand(1..10)) until number == 7
```

Comment: You should pre-define `number` in this case :)

Comment: @AlexGolubenko, fixed :)

Comment: `to_i` is superfluous. And it might be cleaner to express the OP's requirement _"until the number 7"_ as `until number == 7` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
$num = 0
while $num != 7
    $num = rand(1..10)
    print $num.to_s + "\n"
end
puts "over"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the **rand** generated value into num variable,

```
$ num = ''
$ while num != 7
$   num = rand(1..10)
$   print num
$ end
$ # 6168510267=> nil
```